# convert a numbered list into an order list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a python list question:

Input:

```
l=[2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 19, 20, 26, 28, 33, 34, 45, 46, 47, 50, 57, 59, 64, 67, 77, 79, 87, 93, 97, 106, 110, 111, 113, 115, 120, 125, 126, 133, 135, 142, 148, 160, 166, 169, 176, 202, 228, 234, 253, 274, 365, 433, 435, 436, 468, 476, 529, 570, 575, 577, 581, 614, 766, 813, 944, 1058, 1079, 1245, 1363, 1389, 1428, 1758, 2129, 2336, 2402, 2405, 2576, 3013, 3993, 7687, 8142, 8455, 8456]
```

Now I want to write mark the numbers in a [0]*10000 list, such that the beginning is like:

Output:

```
lp=[0,1,0,0,1,...]
```

The second and fifth elements are marked since they appeared in the input.

Comment: The full question is: both l and lp are embedded in a larger list with the same number of lists. L=[l1,l2,...,l100], LP=[lp1,lp2,...,lp100]

Comment: I've reverted the last edit to this question because it changed the meaning too significantly, invaliding the existing answers. If you need additional information please ask a new question instead of extending your existing one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lp = [0] * 10000
for index in l:
    lp[index - 1] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following list comprehension

```
lp = [1 if i in l else 0 for i in range(1, 10001)]
```

Though I'd recommend since `l` could be long that you convert it to a set first

```
set_l = set(l)
lp = [1 if i in set_l else 0 for i in range(1, 10001)]
```

Comment: That's pretty inefficient!

Comment: @PeterWood How do you figure?

Comment: Otherwise you could do `[int(i in l) for i in range(1,10001)]` but that's really the same thing.

Comment: If `l` is small compared to 10,000, then `[0]*10000` followed by a simple loop over `l` will be much faster.

Comment: @Cyber for every entry in the result you do a binary search of the set. If you iterate over the set instead, and index into a list it is linear.